# Double entries showed in gnome applications 12.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

After installing gnome-extensions, some of the entries in the application gnome menu appears twice with different symbols.

Symbols like "Eclipse" symbols appears with the normal symbol AND with the generic symbol for applications. Both are executing the program. 
However, this is a bit disturbing.

Where is this coming from and how can I remove the redundant symbols. 
Cheers
Gerd

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you give screenshot link please. Add some detail about your gnome version. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please try to open the link: 

[https://picasaweb.google.com/114079469770739074976/Public?authkey=Gv1sRgCNLB1bTPhdGbigE] 

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. with gnome-shell as "non-unity" selection.

Comment: Can you upload to imgur.com . Because i got 400 BAD_REQUEST
Unable to process request. Open terminal and type gnome-shell --version

Comment: sorry, try this link: https://picasaweb.google.com/114079469770739074976/Public?authkey=Gv1sRgCNLB1bTPhdGbigE

Comment: if the picasa is not working: than under imgur.com I posted under http://i.imgur.com/ME5NL.png

Comment: post the output of: gnome-shell --version

Comment: I solved it by myself. There must not be redundant entries in other nodes of the main menu. In my case this as been the case for the "Debian" node of the menu. If these entries are deleted, the symbols disappear also in the Application view. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

[Gerd](https://askubuntu.com/users/94994/gerd) solved the problem in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197205/double-entries-showed-in-gnome-applications-12-04#comment245568_197205):

> I solved it by myself. There must not be redundant entries in other nodes of the main menu. In my case this as been the case for the "Debian" node of the menu. If these entries are deleted, the symbols disappear also in the Application view. Cheers